# Unable to set the colors to the bars of barchart according to range of series values in jfreechart

Tags: jsp, jfreechart

> barchart.jsp

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<%@ page import="java.awt.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.axis.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.labels.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.urls.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.category.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.StandardDialScale"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRenderer"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer"%>
<%

class CustomBarRenderer extends BarRenderer {


   private Paint[] m_paints = new Paint[]{Color.blue, Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.pink};

    public CustomBarRenderer() {

    }

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int column) {
        CategoryDataset dataSet = getPlot().getDataset();
        String rowKey = (String)dataSet.getRowKey(series);
        String colKey = (String)dataSet.getColumnKey(column);
        int value = dataSet.getValue(rowKey, colKey).intValue();


         if (series == 1) {
             return m_paints[0];
        }
            if (series == 2) {
                return m_paints[1];

            }
             if (series == 3) {

                return m_paints[2];
            } 
             if (series == 4) {

                return m_paints[3];
            } 
             if (series == 5) {

                return m_paints[4];
            } 

                 return null;

     }
}



DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

final String series1 = "Outsatnding";
final String series2 = "Excellent";
final String series3 = "Very Good";
final String series4 = "Good";
final String series5 = "Average";

dataSet.setValue(32, series3, "Attention to Details");
dataSet.setValue(40, series4, "Systematic Approach");
dataSet.setValue(25, series2, "Communication");
dataSet.setValue(40, series4, "Quality Management");
dataSet.setValue(40, series4, "Network Marketing");
dataSet.setValue(59, series5, "Photography, Videography, Cinematography");
dataSet.setValue(10, series1, "Animation, Graphic Design");
dataSet.setValue(38, series3, "Teaching, Training");

    CategoryPlot plot = null;
    JFreeChart chart =null;
    //BarRenderer renderer= null;
    chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "Details for software programmer ",
            "Competency Name", "Score In Percentage", dataSet,
            PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, false, true, false);
    plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
    chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(java.awt.Color.white);
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setRange(0, 100);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRenderer(new CustomBarRenderer());


  try {
        OutputStream out2 = response.getOutputStream();
        final CategoryAxis dAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();

        dAxis.setTickLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 14));

        final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(
                new StandardEntityCollection());
        final File file1 = new File("/barchart.png");
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out2, chart, 500, 600, info);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!meta  http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <IMG SRC="barchart.png" WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="400" BORDER="0"
        USEMAP="#chart">

</body>
</html>
```

//  I am not getting the colors according to range of values of series.
I am having 5 series of different value range, how to give color to them according to values.
Please can anyone correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**remove**

```
plot.setRenderer(new CustomBarRenderer());
```

**add this for each index**

```
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: I want to set he color depending on value range of series, suppose for outstanding series color is red and for good series color is blue.And series value is taken from database, but first i am trying with static data.

Comment: I dont want to set the color according to series index